# Dynamic String Interpolation for variable output in angular

Tags: angular, variables, string-interpolation

I need to mix the answers to Quiz-Questions in random order.

I have Question objects like:

```json
Question = {
    question: 'what is the capital of Germany?',
    answer1: 'Berlin',
    answer2: 'London',
    answer3: 'Paris',
    answer4: 'Rome'
}
```

Every time I display the Question in the template I generate a random array e.g.

```js
randomOrder = [3,2,0,1]
```

I want to use string interpolation in the template to show the question with random Order of the answers:

```html
Question: {{Question.question}}<br>
Answer1: {{Question.answer'answerOrder[0]'}}<br>
Answer2: {{Question.answer'answerOrder[1]'}}<br>
Answer3: {{Question.answer'answerOrder[2]'}}<br>
Answer4: {{Question.answer'answerOrder[3]'}}<br>
```

Can someone help me with the correct syntax for angular?

Answer (score 1):

Just refer to object by a dynamic key;

```js
Question: {{Question.question}}
Answer1: {{Question['answer'+answerOrder[0]]}}
Answer2: {{Question['answer'+answerOrder[1]]}}
```

Or you could store answers as array like this: `{question: '...', answers: [a,b,c,d]}`

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly the syntax I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

A better aproach is to get a method to return the composed string, using string interpolation, like for example:

```js
questionString(n: number): string {
   return `Answer${n+1}: ${questions['answer'+n]}`;
}
```

And use, for example:

```js
{{question(1)}}
{{question(2)}}
...
```

Or better than, inside a for a loop.